# Zurb Foundation 6: the topbar doesn´t collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm having problemas with Foundation 6, I'm a somplete beginner and I'm trying to apply it to a webpage I'm developing for a project at university. I've directly made a copypaste of the topbar code from the Zurb web page and applied to my project and it doesn't work at all. 
Here's the code I´ve applied:

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
<button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
<div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>
<div class="top-bar" id="example-menu">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
  <ul class="dropdown vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
      <li><a href="#">Asesoreo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="signup_button">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the menu never collapses and the  topbar, which is expected to be hiden while the menu is shown unless the device screen it's small, it's always on sight.

Thanks in advance!

[The Pc screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nRX2.jpg)

[The mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejo1z.jpg)

Comment: Are you loading the Foundation javascript?

Answer (score 1):

here works fine

http://codepen.io/fabiovaz/pen/zrwvjq

please check your js/css path and if you starting foundation

```
$(document).foundation();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
 <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
  <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
  <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>

<div class="top-bar" id="example-menu">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">One</a>
        <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
          <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code gives the same problem as in the question of Albert Marzo.